# Possible to use -WhatIf and the invocation operator (&)?

Tags: powershell, invoke

Is it possible to use the -WhatIf argument when executing external commands? I want to be able to run a script with -WhatIf and have it print out a full list of all the external commands and arguments it's going to run without actually running them.

I've tried doing stuff like the following:

```
Function Invoke-Checked
{
    param([ScriptBlock]$s)

    if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($s.ToString(), "Execute"))
    {
        Invoke-Command $s
    }
}
```

But that won't expand any variables that are present in the scriptblock - doing something like:

```
$s = { & dir $test }
Invoke-Checked $s
```

just prints

```
Performing the operation "Execute" on target " & dir $test ".
```

not particularly helpful.

Is there any way to do what I want?

Comment: Any reason why you want to pass `{ & dir $test }` instead of just `dir $test`, which you could expand at leisure? Of course this does mean you need to replace all uses of `&`, but that seems unavoidable (you need a cmdlet replacement for `&` to support `-WhatIf`). It's the `&` you don't want to do, not the `dir $test`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all - you need to make sure that your 'wrapper' function supports WhatIf.
Another thing: you can expand the scriptBlock, but I'm not really convinced that is smart thing to do: e.g. if `$test = 'Some path with spaces'`, it would stop working after expansion.

That being said: here are two options that work for me: using `GetNewClosure()` method on scriptBlock, and expanding whole thing:

```
function Invoke-ExpandedChecked {
[CmdletBinding(
    SupportsShouldProcess = $true,
    ConfirmImpact = 'Medium'
)]
    param([ScriptBlock]$ScriptBlock)

    $expanded = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($ScriptBlock)
    $script = [scriptblock]::Create($expanded)
    if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($script.ToString(), "Execute"))
    {
        & $script
    }
}

function Invoke-Checked {
[CmdletBinding(
    SupportsShouldProcess = $true,
    ConfirmImpact = 'Medium'
)]
    param([ScriptBlock]$ScriptBlock)

    $newClosure = $ScriptBlock.GetNewClosure()
    if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($newClosure.ToString(), "Execute"))
    {
        & $newClosure
    }
}

$test = '.\DSCDemo.ps_'
$s = { cmd /c dir $test} 

Invoke-Checked $s -WhatIf
Invoke-Checked $s
Invoke-ExpandedChecked $s -WhatIf
Invoke-ExpandedChecked $s
```

And an example of results for path with spaces:

```
$test = 'C:\Program Files'
Invoke-Checked $s
Invoke-ExpandedChecked $s
```

Works fine for one with new enclosure. With expanded:

```
cmd : File Not Found
At line:1 char:2
+  cmd /c dir C:\Program Files
```

Comment: $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($ScriptBlock) was exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to interpret the question to mean, "how do I use -whatif with running external commands?", since that's how I found this question.

```
# myscript.ps1
[cmdletbinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$True)]
Param($path)  # put Param() if no parameters

if ($pscmdlet.ShouldProcess($Path, 'creating folder')) { # not -whatif
  cmd /c mkdir $path
}
```

```
.\myscript foo -whatif
What if: Performing the operation "creating folder" on target "foo".
```